# RShiny Dashboard: No sidebarPanel to access the entire width of the dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shinyapps

I'm using a custom template that doesn't have a sidebar panel. I'm not using the standard shinydashboard library where you can collapse the side panel and then you have access to the entire page.

The issue is that by just using `mainPanel()` it doesn't give me access to the right most 2(?) columns. If I want to center something, I need to specify an empty sidebar, for example: a sidebar with width of 1 and background color white.

How do I access the entire page without a sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

You have other options besides sidebarLayout to structure your app. If you use fixedPage or fluidPage, you can essentially have full control over the structure and placement of your components.